# 2nd While Loop is not running and If statement in the first loop is not running

Tags: python, json

What am I doing wrong here. My first loop runs but not the if statement. second loop doesnt run. This is being used with 5sim.net api.

```
    while 'PENDING' in sms['status']:
       sms = get_status(headers, id)
       time.sleep(5)
       print('Waiting for phone no. to get activated.')
       if sms['status'] == 'RECIEVED':
           print('Phone no. is activated.')
           break
    sms = get_status(headers, id)
    time.sleep(2)    
    while 'RECIEVED' in sms['status']:
        sms = get_status(headers, id)
        time.sleep(5)
        print('Waiting for SMS code')
        if sms['status'] == 'FINISHED':
           break
```

`sms` is a json

```
{'id': xxxxxxx, 'phone': '+xxxxxxxx', 'operator': 'abc', 'product': 'abc', 'price': 24, 'status': 'PENDING', 'expires': '2021-08-21T22:15:39.068961Z', 'sms': [], 'created_at': '2021-08-21T22:00:39.068961Z', 'country': 'usa'}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the structure and content of `sms`.

Comment: Difficult to know without context. But if it is some kind of external API I would probably guess a typo: "RECEIVED" instead of "RECIEVED"?

Comment: added the json.

Comment: The second loop runs if status has a value of "RECIEVED".  But that json has a value of "PENDING" for status.  Why would you expect the second loop to run at all?

Comment: Perhaps it is because RECIEVED is misspelled?  The correct spelling is RECEIVED.

Comment: Can you try adding `print(sms['status'])` below the line `sms = get_status(headers, id)`, to see what the current `sms['status']` actually is?

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for picking up the typo. that might fix it

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt change. You need to manually change `sms["status"]`. Otherwise there is no way to break the loop
Aside that, the if statement is inside the while loop, so if the while doesnt run nor will the if statement.
Probably add a way to change sms["status"] otherwise the loop is not going to run

Comment: sms = get_status(headers, id) this will change the sms['status']

Comment: @nomie `get_status(headers, id)` will return different values for status, even with the same values for headers and id?